# Python type annotation for a function that accepts a type and returns a value of given type

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

I'm trying to annotate a function that parses a string to a specified type and am struggling to find a way to annotate the return type to indicate this.

```
def parse(s: str, t: type) -> t:
    return t(s)
```

Needless to say `-> t:` doesn't work.

I was hoping to make use of generics, but don't see a way to transform the input signature to give it something to infer the `TypeVar` from. Best I came up with distorted the function signature in a weird and confusing way and is not acceptable to do just for the sake of type hinting.

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')


def parse(s: str, to: T) -> T:
    t = type(to)
    return t(s)
```

Is there a way to annotate this function in a way that doesn't modify the runtime signature?

Comment: See [`Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type).

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using [Type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type) as @jonrsharpe suggested.

```
from typing import Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')


def parse(s: str, t: Type[T]) -> T:
    return t(s)


x = parse('123', int)
x = parse('546', int)  # OK
x = parse('324', float)  # mypy error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "float", variable has type "int")
```